# Is there a function in R that allows to select rows where the row name ends in a lower case letter, and remove this letter?

Tags: r

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
data <- as.data.frame(seq(1:5))
rownames(data) <- c("abc-2A","abc-2b", "def-3", "ACD4.54Y", "ghj-5c")
data
             seq(1:5)
abc-2A          1
abc-2b          2
def-3           3
ACD4.54Y        4
ghj-5c          5
```

I would like to do two things with this data frame:

1. Make a subset of this data frame that contains only the rows where there row name ends with a lower case letter. This would be:

   ```
            seq(1:5)
   abc-2b          2
   ghj-5c          5
   ```
2. Remove this lower case letter from the row names in the original `data.frame`. The final `data.frame`  would be:

   ```
        seq(1:5)
   abc-2A          1
   abc-2           2
   def-3           3
   ACD4.54Y        4
   ghj-5           5
   ```

I have spent quite some time in stack overflow and google but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's a bug: in the `rownames` instruction `"ghj-5c"` does not have a `"c"`. Please edit your code.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for spotting it. I've edited the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the `dplyr::filter`function to filter rows according to some criteria.
Lower case letters at the end of a string  can be identified with regular expressions like this `[a-z]$`. Combining all of this yields the following

```
library(dplyr)
  mydata <- data.frame(id = c("select thiss", "DONT SELECT"), x = 1:2) 

mydata %>% 
    filter(grepl("[a-z]$", id)) %>% 
    mutate(id = sub("[a-z]$", "", id))

           id x
1 select this 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was actually my favourite as I've been trying to implement "Tidyverse philosophy" in my coding.

Answer (score 3):

Rownames on a data frame is basically a vector of same length as the columns of the data frame, with additional requirements that it (usually) most be unique and it is forced to be a character vector.

The easiest thing is to start by adding it as an additional column:

```
data$whatever <- rownames(data)
```

Now you can easily do all your usual operations on that column.

To find an element whose last character is a lower case letter, you've got:

```
grepl("[a-z]$", x)
```

where `x` is the vector of interest. To *remove* (i.e. replace the offending character with `""`), use `sub`:

```
sub("[a-z]$", "", x)
```

Put this together and what do you get:

```
rownames(data) <- sub("[a-z]$", "", rownames(data))
```

The difference between `sub` and `gsub` is that `sub` only performs **1** replacement per element, whereas `gsub` performs multiple.

Comment: But this doesn't do the subsetting/filtering OP asked for.

Comment: OP actually isn't asking for filtering, OP is just using subsetting as an intermediate step to identify which elements to perform the operation. Turns out, we don't need to.

Comment: The question currently asks for *"1. Make a subset of this data frame... where row name ends with lowercase letter"*

Comment: Look at the context of the question. Item (1) only asks for that as a mean to get the elements to perform the operation on. Looking at the "final data.frame" in (2), it is clearly not used.

Comment: In addition, the `grepl` command in my answer returns an index vector which can be used for filtering.

Answer (score 2):

To select rows which end with lower case letters (from @Rui Barradas)

```
data[grep("[a-z]$", rownames(data)),, drop = FALSE]

#       seq(1:5)
#abc-2b        2
#ghj-5c        5
```

To change rownames using base R `sub`

```
rownames(data) <- sub("(.*)[a-z]$", "\\1", rownames(data))

data
#         seq(1:5)
#abc-2A          1
#abc-2           2
#def-3           3
#ACD4.54Y        4
#ghj-5           5
```

Comment: And to select them: `data[grep("[a-z]$", rownames(data)),, drop = FALSE]`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas does OP wants to select them? I thought they just showed as a way to reach to final output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works! @RuiBarradas Thanks for the extra piece of code!